# Steam Install not finding internet connection on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: steam

I recently installed Steam on my new Ubuntu install, but whenever I try to run it, I get an error message that says "Fatal Error: Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again". The log file for this goes as follows:

```
[2021-02-21 13:27:18] Startup - updater built Apr  9 2019 22:48:20
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-02-21 13:27:18] Checking for update on startup
[2021-02-21 13:27:18] Checking for available update...
[2021-02-21 13:27:18] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
KeyValues Error: LoadFromBuffer: missing {   (current key: '<!DOCTYPE') in file manifest [offset: 14]

../tier1/KeyValues.cpp (2958) : Assertion Failed: Error while parsing text KeyValues for resource manifest
../tier1/KeyValues.cpp (2958) : Assertion Failed: Error while parsing text KeyValues for resource manifest
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] failed to load manifest from buffer.
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Failed to load manifest
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Error: Download failed: http error 200
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Verifying installation...
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/evanr50/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Verification complete
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Downloading Update...
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Checking for available update...
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
KeyValues Error: LoadFromBuffer: missing {   (current key: '<!DOCTYPE') in file manifest [offset: 14]

../tier1/KeyValues.cpp (2958) : Assertion Failed: Error while parsing text KeyValues for resource manifest
../tier1/KeyValues.cpp (2958) : Assertion Failed: Error while parsing text KeyValues for resource manifest
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] failed to load manifest from buffer.
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Failed to load manifest
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Error: Download failed: http error 200
[2021-02-21 13:27:19] Error: Steam needs to be online to update.     Please confirm your network connection and try again.
[2021-02-21 13:27:20] Shutdown
threadtools.cpp (3225) : Assertion Failed: Illegal termination of worker thread 'Thread(0x0x58633190/0x0xf4c07b'
threadtools.cpp (3225) : Assertion Failed: Illegal termination of worker thread 'Thread(0x0x58633190/0x0xf4c07b'
cat: '/home/evanr50/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.tar.xz.part*': No such file or directory
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/evanr50/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

Have any of you encountered this error before? And do you know how to resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any searching? I used your error with a +linux and a -windows switch to get just Linux results and came across [this](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/534992-Steam-won-t-start-Error-Steam-needs-to-be-online-to-update-Please-confirm-your-network?p=2894685#post2894685) and a few others. That's actually for openSUSE, but it'd be the same for Ubuntu. There were other results as well. That's just the last one I looked at.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and scoured these forums. Here's one you've probably seen before but with a special twist that worked for me:

1. ping media.steampowered.com to get its IP
2. then edit /etc/hosts --- add [The IP] client-download.steampowered.com

The important change for me was "client-download" rather than "media" which is what I'd seen previously and hadn't solved my problem.

Hope this helps